# Nodejs - Passing json object to a event.handler function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, pulse, qtest

Apologies in advance as this is my first time working with NodeJs.

We are using a product called QTest Pulse. In simple terms we have a webhook that is hooked to nodejs file that gets executed on the server and produces results. I am trying to setup my local environment to debug the file to make changes to it.

We usually call the file using a **bash script** like below

```
curl -X POST \
    https://pulse-7.qtestnet.com/webhook/ \
    -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -d @payload.json
```

And the **payload.json** contains data like below

```
{"testcycle" : "178173", "result" : "encrypted data", "projectId" : "90354"}
```

The file on the server **parser.js** contains

```
function processPayload(payload) {
    const projectId = payload.projectId;
    const cycleId = payload.testcycle;

    console.log(projectId);
    console.log(cycleId);
}

exports.handler = function (
    {event: body, constants, triggers},
    context,
    callback
) {
    const formattedResults = processPayload(body);
};
```

I tried to create a file called **runner.js** to invoke the event in parser.js

```
const parser = require('./Parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const jsonContent = fs.readFileSync('payload.json').toString;
let output = parser.handler({body: jsonContent, constants: "", triggers: ""}, "", "");

console.log(output);
```

When I run this, I always get body inside parser.js as undefined. I have also tried to hard code the value instead of reading from the file, Still get the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: typo: `fs.readFileSync('payload.json').toString` you forget to call `toString()`

Comment: exports.handler = function (
    {event: body, constants, triggers},
    context,
    callback
) {

Comment: @xdeepakv - Thanks for getting back. Could you please clarify on the wrong destructure. How should I calling be calling this method. Thanks.

Comment: i added in my answer, correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Mistakes:

1. typo: `fs.readFileSync('payload.json').toString` you forget to call `toString()`
2. You are doing wrong destructure. You are already sending body.

   exports.handler = function (
     {**body**, constants, triggers},
     context,
     callback
   ) {
     const formattedResults = processPayload(body);
   };